# XML Conversion to CSV with jsaon loads

Tags: python, xml, csv

Hell All , I'm new to python and I have a request to convert XML to CSV..can any 1 help me on it..here the XML text what I have and I used following code ..but it works fine only if there are no curly brakets in the data ..but these days we are getting curly brakets in the data ..pls suggest how I can do it..

I'm getting error as un disclosed string in json.loads..

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encodning="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://wwww.w3.org/2002/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GRPtRes
            xmlns="testatatstip">
            <GRPtresult>
                <Dob>
                    <RData>[{"unid:1234,"test":"testst","enterdata":"tetst}dfd{", "restdata":"testagain"},{"unid:123456565,"test":"tesfdftst","enterdata":"teddtstdfd", "restdata":"testagadfdin"},{"unid:12343434,"test":"test43st","enterdata":"tetstdfd", "restdata":"testadfdgain"}]</RData>
                    <Nofpage>1</Nofpage>
                </Dob>
                <resp>good</resp>
                <succe>true</succe>
            </GRPtresult>
        </GRPtRes>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks for u r support

PK

I tried xml tree but no luck

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt at a solution. In the end, do you actually want the (invalid) imbedded json as your csv? Assuming it was in fact valid json?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas, if you xml declaration is right see [4.3.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding) I corrected it here:

```
import pandas as pd
from json import loads, dumps
from pprint import pprint

xml="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://wwww.w3.org/2002/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GRPtRes
            xmlns="testatatstip">
            <GRPtresult>
                <Dob>
                    <RData>[{"unid:1234,"test":"testst","enterdata":"tetst}dfd{", "restdata":"testagain"},{"unid:123456565,"test":"tesfdftst","enterdata":"teddtstdfd", "restdata":"testagadfdin"},{"unid:12343434,"test":"test43st","enterdata":"tetstdfd", "restdata":"testadfdgain"}]</RData>
                    <Nofpage>1</Nofpage>
                </Dob>
                <resp>good</resp>
                <succe>true</succe>
            </GRPtresult>
        </GRPtRes>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

df = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='.//xmlns:GRPtresult', namespaces={"xmlns": "testatatstip"})
df.to_csv('Test.csv')

result = df.to_json(orient="index")
parsed = loads(result)
dumps(parsed, indent=4)

pprint(parsed)
```

File:

```
,Dob,resp,succe
0,,good,True
```

Output:

```
{'0': {'Dob': None, 'resp': 'good', 'succe': True}}
```